# How can I tailor the Route Optimization code to show complete directions instead of the route summary?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Google offers an example on Route Optimization on this webpage: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=en#DirectionsRequests
which links out to
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

I'd like to create a variation of this code. In my version, I'd like to show the complete set of directions instead of a simple summary. I tried simply cutting the code after "// For each route, display summary information", but that didn't work. How can I tailor it so that it shows the full directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the panel-option of the directionsRenderer to a node that should receive the results.

For the given example it would be:

```
directionsDisplay 
 = new google.maps
    .DirectionsRenderer({panel:document.getElementById('directions_panel')});
```

There is  an example in the same page: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I'm still having no luck integrating the two codes. Here's my code: [https://gist.github.com/4297411#file-map-code] When I use this, the map and the control panel appear, but the directions do not process and the directions panel does not appear.

Comment: Whoops! Never mind. I got it to work. All I needed to do was take the original code, find the .DirectionsRenderer at the top, and paste in the code you provided between the parentheses. Thanks for making my day, Dr. Molle!